# Image keeps dissapearing when position is updated

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making this game in pygame(python) where you have to click the targets, and every time you click the target it's position get's updated.

The problem is, that each time new position (code line: 27) is set to the target, it only appears for a split second but immediately dissapears.

here's the code:

```
import pygame, random

pygame.init()
SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
pygame.font.init()

#GLOBALS
WHITE = 255,255,255
SCALE = TWIDTH, THEIGHT = 100, 100
score = 0
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)

class Target(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("target.png"), SCALE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = random.randrange(0,WIDTH-self.image.get_width())
        self.y = random.randrange(0,HEIGHT-self.image.get_height())

    def spawn_target(self):
        WIN.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def new_position(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(0,WIDTH-self.image.get_width())
        self.y = random.randrange(0,HEIGHT-self.image.get_height())

    def target_hit(self, mouse):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse):
            all_sprites.remove(target)


class Update():
    def __init__(self, color, score):
        self.color = color
        self.mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.score = score
    
    def draw_mouse(self):
        self.mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        pygame.draw.circle(WIN, "cyan", self.mousepos, 5)

    def update_window(self):
        WIN.fill(self.color)

        if len(all_sprites) <= 0:
            all_sprites.add(target)
            target.spawn_target()
            target.new_position()
            self.score += 1

        print(len(all_sprites))
        self.draw_mouse()
        SCORE = font.render(f"Score: {self.score}", 1, (0,0,0))
        WIN.blit(SCORE, (5, 5))
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, "red", target, 2) #Draw target hitbox
        pygame.display.update()

target = Target()
update = Update(WHITE, score)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True
    while running:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for s in all_sprites:
                    s.target_hit(event.pos)

        pygame.display.set_caption(f"Framerate {clock.get_fps(): 0.0f}")
        update.update_window()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[Tried assigning new image position in different methods but nothing helpe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyUMD.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spawn_target` is only executed once when a new target spawns. So it makes no sense to draw the target in `spawn_target`. You have to redraw the scene in every frame and draw the the sprite in the Group `all_sprites`:

```py
class Target(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def spawn_target(self):
        # WIN.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))  <--- DELETE
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

```py
class Update():
    # [...]

    def update_window(self):
        WIN.fill(self.color)

        if len(all_sprites) <= 0:
            all_sprites.add(target)
            target.new_position()
            target.spawn_target()
            self.score += 1

        print(len(all_sprites))
        
        all_sprites.draw(WIN)                    # <--- INSERT

        self.draw_mouse()
        SCORE = font.render(f"Score: {self.score}", 1, (0,0,0))
        WIN.blit(SCORE, (5, 5))
        # pygame.draw.rect(WIN, "red", target, 2) #Draw target hitbox
        pygame.display.update()
```